# Where to catch user control properties being wrapped to be loaded inside a modal?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, simplemodal, page-lifecycle

I have a user control which has a public property (e.g. AlarmID) and this control is wrapped inside a div and when user presses a button on the page, in code-behind the public property of that user control becomes set. then a ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is called to show a modal popup which is a div wrapping that control.

My problem is that although in code-behind I first set the public property of that user control, but when the modal popup shows that user control, I cannot access that property

I used Control_PreRender, and Control_Load events but none of them were able to show the correct value of that property in a label inside that control.

For more clarification, here is my code in the code-behind of the control:

```
protected void Control_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblAlarmCode.Text = alarmID.ToString();
        }

        public int AlarmID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.alarmID;
            }
            set
            {
                this.alarmID = value;
            }
        }
```

What is the exact life-cycle event in which I can catch the property to be shown correctly by that label?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the modal is attached to the `<form>` element on the page otherwise it will not be a part of the page lifecycle at all.

Just as a sample, not saying this is your code, but I had to use something similar in order to have `<asp:Textbox>` and `<asp:Button>` controls to be brought back and forth across the Request

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlWorkItem">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <label>Job Code</label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlJobCode" Width="50%" />

        <label>Hours</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHours" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <p><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddWorkItem" OnClick="btnAddWorkItem_Click" text="Add Work Item" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var workItemPanel = $("#<%= pnlWorkItem.ClientID %>");
    workItemPanel.hide();
    $("#add-work").on("click", function () {
        $(workItemPanel).dialog({
            width: 450,
            height: 300
        }).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
    });
});
```

It will append your element to the form element generated by ASP.net and should have your properties set and carried across.

Comment: Make sure you mark my response as the answer if it fixes your problem!

Comment: Thanks but your solution requires major modifications to current code structure which tends me to avoid

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the label in setter. However there might be other solutions but this ways is just working.